# Why was this question about svchost HDD thrashing closed?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question: [Who is reading my hard drive? (svchost)](https://serverfault.com/questions/609425/who-is-reading-my-hard-drive-svchost)

Can you please clarify why it is off-topic?

I could make a case that a professional could have an issue with svchost doing unneeded and unnecessary HDD reads and needs to find an answer.

I am curious what had my question sound not professional, and if there is a SE forum that could address my concern better.

Comment: In addition to the answers, professionals tend to know what svchost is, and rather than asking questions about why a system process is behaving normally, are irritated by such questions.

Answer (score 10):

1. This has been closed two years ago. Why bother with it now?
2. Unless you **really** know what you are doing, it's generally considered bad practice to fiddle around in internal settings of Windows. Contrary to popular belief, Windows 7 (and upwards) is actually quite good at running as fast and optimal as possible by itself, and trying to outsmart it mostly ends bad. Thus, I would consider it very bad professional practice to try what you do, making it off-topic on a site that exclusively deals with professsional system administraton. It appears, five people agreed with me on that and closed the question.
3. Also it's a typical beginners trap to want all system resources to be as unused as possible. That's crap. I want my system to use all resources it has if it can use them in a beneficiary way. Windows does this. It uses the RAM as cache, and it indexes and rearranges the disk for faster search and optimized startup times when idle, but it stops doing so if something else has better use for the resources. That's GREAT and I don't want to stop it.
4. At no point did you demonstrate you had an actual problem, e.g. performance of the system was really degraded in any way by the activity.
5. Wear leveling on modern SSDs is good enough that standard windows operations will likely have no noticeable impact on the longevity of the disk. This is even more true in 2016 then in 2014, but I find the idea to invest the time saved by having much faster disks back into the system by trying to over-"optimize" the OS installation kind of silly.

Comment: "That's crap. I want my system to use all resources it has if it can use them in a beneficiary way. " if only that could be said more often.

Answer (score 8):

That question was closed **two years ago** with a then default  close reason:

> "Questions must be relevant to professional system administration. Server Fault is dedicated to professional system and network administrators. End user and enthusiast questions are off-topic (contact your system administrator or hire a professional to help you out).

Your question appears to me as indeed one  an end-user or enthusiast would ask because it reads as more about idle curiosity than a professional investigating an actual problem.
With current Q&A standards I would still expect your question to end up closed by the community for more or less the same reason.

The default close reason has been updated though and now suggests asking instead on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) which caters to computer enthusiasts and power users.